# Search Youtube video through android app

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am making app that search Yoututbe video through the app. But it throw exception on `SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();`
How to resolve this problem. Please help

below is my exception that raise during search perform

```
    05-07 12:26:33.163 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
05-07 12:26:33.164 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.dp.videostoreadmin.MainActivity.displaySearchResult(MainActivity.java:62)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.dp.videostoreadmin.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:22)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.dp.videostoreadmin.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
05-07 12:26:33.165 26111-26111/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

below is my code

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyCxmfKGyNqlQIEtY0XWxGzC4QHX08BWmks";
    EditText searchText;
    Button submit;
    private static YouTube youtube;
    private static final long NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED = 25;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displaySearchResult();
            }
        });
    }

    private void displaySearchResult() {

        try {

             youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
               }
            }).setApplicationName("VideoStoreAdmin").build();

            YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
            search.setKey(YOUTUBE_API_KEY);
            search.setQ(searchText.getText().toString());
            search.setType("video");
            search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/publishedAt,snippet/thumbnails/default/url),nextPageToken");
            search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

            // Call the API and print results.
            SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
            List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
            if (searchResultList != null) {
                Log.d("TAG",searchResultList.toString());
            }
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Prompt the user to enter a query term and return the user-specified term.
     */



}
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914165/how-to-search-videos-with-youtube-data-api-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914165/how-to-search-videos-with-youtube-data-api-in-android) Refer to this maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error is not about the youtube actually, you are doing network operation on the main UI thread that is not allowed.

You need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for running separate thread for network operation. Your Network operation will work inside the doInBackground() method.

After you get response from the API you need to do all UI change in onPostExecute() method.

**NOTE : You can not do any UI change operation in doInBackground(). It will throw an Exception.**

```
private class YoutubeSearchAPI extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName("VideoStoreAdmin").build();

            YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
            search.setKey(YOUTUBE_API_KEY);
            search.setQ(searchText.getText().toString());
            search.setType("video");
            search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/publishedAt,snippet/thumbnails/default/url),nextPageToken");
            search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

            // Call the API and print results.
            SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
            List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
            if (searchResultList != null) {
                Log.d("TAG",searchResultList.toString());
            }
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        //Do All UI Changes HERE
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

You can call this class with this line

```
new YoutubeSearchAPI().execute();
```